# Please explain me about || signal in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please explain me what does || signal means in javascript. I have some lines like this:

```
a=a||{};
a.checkURL=a.checkURL||window.location.href;
a.checkInterval=a.checkInterval||5E3;
```

This code use **||** signal many times. May anybody help me to explain.

Comment: Its called short-circuit evaluation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Whenever I use || I refer to it as or, but not in the logical sense. In psuedo:  `var a equals a or (if null or undefined or false) {}`
a.checkURL = a.checkURL -OR if it doesn't exist - window.location.href
Same with if statements:
`if (a === b || a === C){//match!}` would be:
`if a is exactly equal to b -OR (if that result didn't return true) - if a is exactly equal to c`

Comment: thank you, gurvinder372. Because it is a little hard to search || signal on google ^^